# Individual weights per class for each sample in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

In Keras (tensorflow backend) I can weight the classes via a parameter, and there is another parameter that allows the weighting of the samples (as it was referenced in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459317/keras-class-weight-vs-sample-weights-in-the-fit-generator))

In my case, I need to do both simultaneously: each sample should have an individual weight for each of the two classes that I have. My problem is that I don't just have one weight per sample for both classes, but the two classes need individual weights for each sample.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to understand. Can you provide an example/more detail? E.g. what is the dimensionality of your data, what weights per class do you want, and what weights per sample?